# Typescript - Cannot find name 'By'

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a problem with my Angular unit tests in Karma and TypeScript.

With the code

```
fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.mat-select-trigger')).nativeElement.click();
```

I get an error `[ts] Cannot find name 'By'.`

What am I missing here? The only available import is `import { by } from 'protractor'` but I believe it's not that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For import the "By". You have need use `platform-browser`, like this :

```
import {By} from "@angular/platform-browser";
```

Comment: wow, thank you very much. I don't know why my IDE was suggesting only the protractor 'by'.

Comment: You're welcome ! Because it's have been same property in Protractor,

Comment: yes, I know, I am only wondering why it didn't see the `{ By }` from `"@angular/platform-browser"` at all.